# Charts template folder

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I've developed a superuseful addon which recreates source data for charts "disconnected" from Excel. So I `.SaveChartTemplate` then `ApplyChartTemplate` to a new chart, and need to delete temp. template.

Don't know how to get chart template folder. I assume that it's `Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Шаблоны\Charts\"` but it's obvious that it works only with russian locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing registry keys, i've come to realize that templates folder name  can be found in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\<OFFICE VERSION>\Common\General\Templates`

[image: Templates in registry]

Assuming the above a possible solution is

```
Function chartTemplatesFolder() As String
    On Error GoTo er:
    Dim templatesFolder As String
    templatesFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead( _
        "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Common\General\Templates")
    chartTemplatesFolder = Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\" & templatesFolder & "\Charts\"
Exit Function
er:
End Function
```